# Background execution of function every 10 minutes? Xcode iOS 8

Tags: background, ios8, alerts

Hey i am new to iOS programming.i am working on an app which must alert a person with a small chime hourly.I have created a function which checks time and play the chime when its for example 12:00 PM. Function is working well when app is opened and active.But unfortunately after researching a lot on goole and stack overflow i couldn't get a proper answer.i did activated audio and airplay in background plist in Xcode.I would be grateful if anyone could help me how to keep running the function which checks time every 10 minutes and plays the chime in background and when phone is locked as well.This is my first post to stack overflow.Thanks in advance.Other approach to achieve this goal is also welcomed.

Comment: Check this- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5616687?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps are not allowed to continue running background tasks for extended periods of time. This is because doing so could have a huge negative impact on battery life and performance in the rest of the operating system. However, in your situation, what you would probably want to do is schedule local `UINotification`s to go off at your desired times.  Look at Apple's [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and your support.I had one ore question.Since m using AVspeechutterance and speechsyntesizer for text to speech.How will i code my uilocalnotification to speak the utterance.

Comment: Probably the best option would be to write the speech utterance to a file (not familiar with `AVSpeechUtterance`s so I'm not sure how that would work) and setting the notification's `soundName` property to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach to this would be by setting local notifications with an hourly interval. You can assign the "chimes" sound to your local notification.

And with this approach there is just no need to check for the time every 10 minutes.

You can also check for the intervals you can use for setting time intervals for local notifications on the following link and setup the correct one for your application:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html

That was it.. Happy coding..!!